# How can I encrypt a folder in linux using only the command line?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, encryption

I need to encrypt a folder with documents (about 560kb if that makes any difference) and I was wondering whether it was possible to accomplish that using the command line?

I am searching for something like this:

```
encrypt /path/to/folder encryption_method password
```

than can be decrypted the same way

```
decrypt /path/to/folder encryption_method password
```

Comment: What counts as "unnecessary software"?  The software to encrypt and decrypt would probably be necessary for this sort of problem, right?

Comment: I was referring to bloat-ware and it would be preferable to use the software that is pre-installed if there are any. Sorry if that was unclear. I will edit the question and remove that part completely.

Comment: Have a look at `encfs`to have directories encrypted and used as filesystem to mount, even automatically with `libpam-encfs`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `encfs`: It mounts a dir on another dir, so that the files are stored encrypted as normal files. This way you do not need to make a block device.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for *dm-crypt* and *cryptsetup*.

Basically you encrypt a block device and mount it as directory

Answer (score 1):

Another nice option here is to use the tool that has been written by Dyne.

https://github.com/dyne/Tomb

It is a nice set of scripts that handle a number of Unix tools to make encrypting Folders / Files easier.

Main page for the tool is [here.](https://www.dyne.org/software/tomb/)